# Limit the number of characters in two specific textfields

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm trying to limit the number of characters in two specific textfields (there are four in total). I was able to successfully do this for one textfield but not both. The max character limit should be 36 for both. Can anyone help me with this? Below is what I have so far. Note: I'm a novice programmer, so please forgive me if there's an obvious answer to this question. Thanks.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let maxLength = 36
    let currentString: NSString = (fullNameTextField.text ?? "") as NSString
    
    let currentString2: NSString = (occupationTextField.text ?? "") as NSString
    
    let newString: NSString =
        currentString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString
    return newString.length <= maxLength
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of getting the text from `fullNameTextField` and `occupationTextField`, use the `textField` parameter.

But if you want to limit the number of characters in only `fullNameTextField` and `occupationTextField`, add an `if` statement.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    
    /// check the textField
    if textField == fullNameTextField || textField == occupationTextField {
        let maxLength = 36
        let currentString: NSString = (textField.text ?? "") as NSString
        let newString: NSString = currentString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString
        return newString.length <= maxLength
    }
    
    /// don't limit characters if textField is NOT `fullNameTextField` or `occupationTextField`
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to limit the characters in the other 2 textfields. There are four in total, and I'm trying to limit the characters in only two of them.

Comment: @safetotry just realized that right when you posted your comment. Edited.